# Google Analytics and Adwords API's: Duplicate Adwords data

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I've got a client who has several different websites, each with their own Google Analytics account.  Our marketing department is also running Google Adwords ads for each of those websites.  There is a single Adwords account serving all websites for this client (different ads for each website, naturally.)  I've got the Adwords account linked into each of the Analytics accounts.  Per client's request, I've written a custom dashboard for each site that pulls in data via the Analytics API and displays various summaries.

My problem is when I pull data from the Analytics API, all the Adwords-related numbers are identical among the different sites (e.g. `ga:adCost`, `ga:adClicks`, `ga:CTR`).  But this can't be true, since the websites and their ads are all different and each pair would have to be performing differently.  The Analytics numbers vary as expected though (e.g. `ga:visitors`, `ga:avgTimeOnSite`, `ga:visits`)

I've been Googling and experimenting with the Analytics API docs, and I'm stumped.  How can I pull website-specific Adwords data via the Analytics API?  Is this even possible?  I see no GA dimensions that would allow me to filter by Adwords target domain name, but maybe I missed something.  I've been holding off trying to connect with the Adwords API directly, in attempt to keep things simple.  But it's looking like I may not have a choice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.  I realized I could filter on `ga:adwordsCampaignId`.  Since our marketing department has a different Adwords campaign for each site, and only *one* campaign for each site, this works.

Comment: did you face anything like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19364223/google-adwords-api-issues-in-order-by-clause-and-average-cpc-calculations

Answer (score 1):

Curtis, you should be able to filter it by using *adDestinationUrl* dimension, and then filter the results down by domain name, for example.