# Google Adwords API Issues in "ORDER BY" clause and Average CPC calculations

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-ads-api

I am working on my clients MCC account for reporting functionalities.

I am using Google Adwords PHP API version v201309 (latest).

Ok while fetching the resultset with AWQL (Reporting/DownloadCriteriaReportWithAwql.php) i am facing one query error while executing that file.

which is : `Type = 'QueryError.INVALID_ORDER_BY_CLAUSE', Trigger = '', FieldPath = ''.`

while there is nothing wrong in my query :

```
$dateRange = sprintf('%d,%d',
date('Ymd', strtotime('1989-01-01')), date('Ymd', strtotime('now')));

'SELECT CampaignId, CampaignName, AverageCpc, Conversions,
Cost, Date FROM CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT 
WHERE CampaignName 
IN ["Local  - Search", "Local - Display", "Display New Landing"] 
DURING '.$dateRange.' ORDER BY Date';
```

Another issue i am facing is of Average CPC, there is a different amount in client MCC account and in API response output for particular date.
i want to clarify you that i am using AWQL (Reporting/DownloadCriteriaReportWithAwql.php) which creates direct .csv file of output.

Please check screenshots.

- CSV FILE OUTPUT

[image]

- Live MCC Account

[image]

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 1):

[The Google Developers page on Reports in AdWords Scripts](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/features/reports) states that

> reports do not support the ORDER BY or LIMIT clauses. Results will be
>   returned in no particular order.

I was outputting to a Google Spreadsheet. My solution was to do make a second sheet that sorted the outputted data by the formula `=sort('Account Last Month'!A2:E32;1;true)`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `ORDER BY Date` to `ORDER BY Date ASC`